# How To Hide Div Elements when Inspect Element?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a validator like this,

```
        checkAmount: function(){

            if(){
                //true
                $("#a").removeClass("d-none");
            }
            else{
            //false
                $("#a").addClass("d-none");
            }

        }
```

but when I inspect the div element it still appears like this

```
<div id="a" class="col-md-7 offset-md-5 d-none"></div>
```

and I can easily remove the d-none class that was used for validation

The question is how do I hide the div when it is false so that I can't inspect the element?

Comment: You can't do like that because you can't handle developer tools functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove html from your DOM

```
 $("#a").remove();
```

if you want to hide only then use

```
$("#a").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

$("DOM").hide(); can be used to hide element

$("DOM"). remove(); can be used to remove element which u can't see in browser inspect element

Answer (score -1):

```
$("DOM").hide();
```

you can use this **hide** method to hide elements

```
$("DOM").remove();
```

you can **remove** method to remove any hidden inspects elements